# How to create entity classes from database using spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-tool-suite

I'm working on a spring boot application using spring data jpa at Spring Tool Suite IDE. I need to create entity classes from database but I couldn't find any answer to how to do it.

I saw an answer about adding  JPA Facet adding and using it. But I couldn't add JPA Facet because my application is  maven web , not jee application.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] - Also read our [ask] page to improve this question.  As it stands, it does not meet the community guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Mapping from db table -> entity:

1. Eclipse:
   Make an empty JPA Project, set data sources and use JPA Tools > Generate entities from Tables. Then copy-paste model classes to your project.
   [image: JPA Tools]
2. IntelliJ:
   Install plugin **JPA Buddy** and make a reverse engineering:
   [Reverse engineering video](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiYk-Cn0sz2AhUWk2oFHS3lCqAQwqsBegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Daz9ghvGczys&usg=AOvVaw2I2y2K3G08FOXhGnDG7FbW)
3. Netbeans:
   [How to](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/02/netbeans-java-ee-tip-1-entity-classes-database.html)

---

If you know other ways to generate entities, please tell us.

Answer (score -1):

You don't create entity classes from database. You create models to map your table and its relationships with other tables.

1. Application Properties to configure JPA mapping.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

2. Map your classes to a table.

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html#simple

Comment: what would i do if i have 30 database tables in mysql and I WANT spring make use of that schema?
That "YOU DON'T" seems to be very prohibitive.
I'm right now figuring out  if an eclipse plugin: Telosys code generator can do the job, also i know that JPA Buddy in IntelliJ could work.